# How would I invoke a function only once, with any further invocations returning the last value from the first invocation?

Tags: javascript, function, return, invoke

My goal with the code below is to have whatever function passed into fn to ONLY be invoked once. e.g. result returns 5 and the repeated invocation below should also return that same number. What I have right now keeps returning a new number instead of the same one.

```js
function once(fn) {
    var done = false;
    
    return function () {
        if (!done) {
            done = true;
            return fn.apply(this, arguments);
        } else if (done) {
            return fn.apply(this, arguments);
        }
    };
    
}

function add(x, y) {
    return x + y;
}

var addOnce = once(add);
var result = addOnce(2, 3);
result = addOnce(4, 4);
```

Comment: please add the wanted results as well.

Comment: Hi Alex. Welcome to stackoverflow!. I am not 100% sure what you are trying to accomplish. However, I have a feeling that [*function and yield](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*) might be the answer to your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For getting the same value, you could store the value and return it for every call.

```js
function once(fn) {
    var done = false,
        value;

    return function() {
        if (!done) {
            done = true;
            value = fn.apply(this, arguments);
        }
        return value;
    };
}

function add(x, y) {
    return x + y;
}

var addOnce = once(add);

console.log(addOnce(2, 3)); // 5
console.log(addOnce(4, 4)); // 5
```